# how to create two primary key with alter table

Tags: mysql, primary-key, alter-table

I have table broker with this form

```
broker
{
broker_code char(10) primary key

.

.

.
}
```

and i have add to it another primary key with this form

code int nut null  auto_increment

and wrote this query

```
ALTER TABLE broker ADD code INT  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (code);
```

but it this error.

```
multiply primary key defined.
```

what can i do?

Comment: Why do you need another PRIMARY key and AUTO_INCREMENT? What exactly the requirement is? Consider to explain.

Comment: And what do you need another PK for? Can't you go with an index key, possibly with two columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have two primary keys... However, you can have a "candidate" key or Unique that also prevents duplication on other criteria... Such as a person in a human resources application.  You can have an internal "employee ID" which is the primary, but also a candidate key on a person's Social Security Number which SHOULD never be duplicated... and if so, it would through up a red-flag to H/R to verify who a person is.

Answer (score 2):

This code below has a composite primary key with alter table.

```
ALTER TABLE ex_table
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`name`,`id`)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure because I can't see the structure of your current table 'broker'.
But my guess is that you already defined another Primary Key.

You are only allowed to have 1 primary key per table.